# How can I parse out some items from a string in c#

Tags: c#

I have strings like this:

```
/Administration/References
/Administration/Menus/Home
```

etc

Is there an easy way that I can find the 1st, 2nd and 3rd words that appear in these strings and place it into an array. ie. the text between the slashes?

Comment: `String.Split` is what you want. Search for that either here on the MSDN for more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way in this case is

```
var words = myString.Split(new[]{'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

This will give you an array of all the words seperated by the slashes.

The `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` will make sure that you don't get empty entries, since the string is starting with a / it will give an empty first element in the array. If you have a trailing / it will give a empty last element as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
string.Split(new char[] { '/' })
```

See MSDN for more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the split method on string i.e.

```
string[] words = yourstring.Split('/');
```

Answer (score 0):

It will give you a List that contains 1st line, 2nd line and etc. Each list item is an Array of strings that you want to parse.

```
    private List<string[]> ParseText(string text)
    {
        string[] lines = text.Split(new string[] { System.Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();
        foreach (var item in lines)
        {
            list.Add(item.Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
        }
        return list;
    }
```